# Prevent double click on application focus

Tags: macos, mouse, window-manager, click

When I click on an application in OSX, this focuses the application and raises it to the front, but does not pass the click through to the application. However, I frequently wish to focus an application to perform an action, and my Windows/Linux training has taught me to click where I want my click to register. In OSX, this becomes a problem because I click once to focus and a second time to trigger a click event - but the window responds as though to a *double* click - when toggling something with a click, the window focus click is only treated as a click when I send another, toggling the object twice.

What setting(s) should I change to support either passing that first click like other popular [WIMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WIMP_(computing)) GUIs or to consume that first click completely and use it *only* for focusing the window? If not settings, are there software that solve this problem?

Comment: Related questions about enabling focus follows mouse: [27306](http://superuser.com/questions/27306/focus-follows-mouse-or-sloppy-focus-on-mac-os-x), [34446](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34446/enable-click-through-preferrably-for-all-applications), [98310](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98310/focus-follows-mouse-plus-auto-raise-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: @LauriRanta I _really don't_ want any kind of focus follows mouse please thank you.

Comment: Isn't focus follows mouse without auto-raise (or without any visual changes) basically the same as always enabling click-through? FFM with auto-raise is not really usable on OS X though.

Comment: @LauriRanta They are not the same: I would like keyboard focus to remain where it is no matter where I hover my mouse. Though it is possible to force "click-through" using focus follows mouse, this would result in focus following mouse, which is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Some applications does send the click through. For example the calculator. Open the calculator, type some numbers in it, focus another window and then click the C calculator's button: the typed numbers are replaced by a zero.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pending a better answer - in Cocoa applications on OSX I can force a "click through" to the lower window without focusing it by ⌘-clicking. This appears to be a good solution - just needs to be more discoverable.

Comment: This fixes most of my grudges, except for putting focus directly into a text field