# Change application and select text with a single click

Tags: macos, windows

I'm fairly certain that, prior to Yosemite, it was possible to click in a non-active app's edit pane to put the caret at that point. It now requires two clicks: one to change which application and then a second to put the caret at the desired place. Has anyone else observed this change or know why it was made?

More importantly, how can I get this behaviour back? I seem to do a lot of work where I select text in one app, copy it, and then want to insert it in a new app. The above change in behaviour is pretty infuriating :-(

Comment: The current behaviour has been like that in all versions of OS X. There are some programs e.g. iTerm that do allow this but it is on a program by programs basis

Comment: Mac default has always been 1st click to activate, 2nd click to interact.

Comment: @Tetsujin - any way to change that default?

Comment: short answer, no, sorry. It's a Windows thing, one that drives me bananas whenever I have to use Win.

Comment: Funny, 'cos having to use side by side apps on mac is doing the same thing to me...

Comment: I can select text in inactive application with `⌘ CMD` + Click (Right/Seccondary click also works with `⌘ CMD`), however it does not work for placing the carret in a desired place. But with this You can "swap" the workflow -> active app would be the one where You are pasting the text - inactive is the one where You select and copy things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's always been this broken, maybe I just never hit it because I haven't used multi-monitor macs before and so rarely had windows side-by-side:

https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2436615

[Enable click-through, preferrably for all applications](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34446/enable-click-through-preferrably-for-all-applications)

:-(