# Disable click-through on all applications

Tags: system-settings, utilities

If a window does not have focus, clicking on it should raise it to the foreground and focus it, but it should *not* pass the click to the window.

There is an app "Klicko" (https://brockerhoff.net/klicko/index.html) that does this, but it has last been updated in 2008 and no longer works on my Big Sur Intel machine.

As you can see, my question is the opposite of [Enable click-through, preferrably for all applications](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34446/enable-click-through-preferrably-for-all-applications)

Comment: I've always found *most* apps do behave like this, with exceptions for the window dots, etc. I too hate it - every time I use Windows, which doesn't respect it & yet counter-intuitively ignores mouse-scroll, which I *do* like. Are you finding it on specific apps?

Comment: Very interesting.  Thank you for the feedback.  Indeed, some applications swallow the click that focuses them (tried Mail, Safari, and iTerm).  But I often use IntelliJ, which acts on the first click, and does not swallow it.  I.e. click-through is on in IntelliJ.  I believe there is another app but I can't find it right now.

Comment: That will be the 'fault' [or conscious choice] of the developers. I'd suggest filing a bug report with them.